# Need help parsing a CSV file using jquery in sharepoint environment

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, csv

I'm working on a mini-app in html/javascript that reads a CSV file, and visually outputs the information in it.  Pretty straightforward stuff, or so I thought.  I've got it working just fine locally (in firefox), and over http across all browsers.  But when I gave it to the client, the csv would not load, presumably because of security restrictions within their Sharepoint environment.  Any suggestions?

I'm currently reading the information from the CSV using:

```
function openCsv(whichCsv){ //loads the CSV file which.csv
resetApp();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: whichCsv,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {processData(data);}
    });
}
```

Comment: Open your browser debug panel, go to the NETWORK tab, run the code and watch for errors.